# Nodejs mysql queries which depend on each other

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to write two mysql queries with nodejs. The second query uses result from the first one. The problem is that the second query starts to execute when the first one isn't finished yet.
Any ideas how I could fix this?
Thanks ! Here is the code below:

```
let userId;
let username;
let password;
let token;

connection.query("SELECT user_id from proxy_pairs WHERE id = " + connection.escape(proxyPairId), function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err

    userId = rows[0].user_id;
})


connection.query("SELECT username, password, token from accounts WHERE id = " + connection.escape(userId), function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err

    username = rows[0].username;
    password = rows[0].password;
    token = rows[0].token;

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work as the queries will be executed asynchronously. To make this work you have 3 options.

1. Nesting the calls.
2. Use promises.
3. Use async/await.

The most simple way is nesting the calls.

This will work with nesting the calls.

```
let userId;
let username;
let password;
let token;

connection.query("SELECT user_id from proxy_pairs WHERE id = " + connection.escape(proxyPairId), function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err

    userId = rows[0].user_id;

    connection.query("SELECT username, password, token from accounts WHERE id = " + connection.escape(userId), function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err

        username = rows[0].username;
        password = rows[0].password;
        token = rows[0].token;

    })
})
```

You should refer to promises and async/await for different solutions. And I would prefer promises or async/await for this situation, but you are free to choose your own.

Answer (score 0):

Make a second call inside the callback:

```
connection.query("SELECT user_id from proxy_pairs WHERE id = " + connection.escape(proxyPairId), function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err

    userId = rows[0].user_id;

    connection.query("SELECT username, password, token from accounts WHERE id = " + connection.escape(userId), function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err

    username = rows[0].username;
    password = rows[0].password;
    token = rows[0].token;

  })
})
```

Instead of callbacks depending to the version of node you are using I would suggest to use [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) or [async/await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) to structure the queries.